# Source of Cubic term in Julia's DiffEqFlux Example on the Lotka Volterra Model

Tags: julia, ode, flux.jl

I am playing around with the sample codes in DiffEqFlux library of Julia here:
https://github.com/SciML/DiffEqFlux.jl/blob/master/README.md#training-a-neural-ordinary-differential-equation.

```
function trueODEfunc(du,u,p,t)
    true_A = [-0.1 2.0; -2.0 -0.1]
    du .= ((u.^3)'true_A)'
end
```

I believe true_A is the Jacobian of the Lotka-Volterra model. Yet I do not understand the mathematical source of the u.^3 in du. 
Please kindly direct me or explain how the u.^3 comes about. 
Thank you!

Comment: This is just a choice of what data to generate.

Comment: Hi Chris, do u mean it's there to serve as an example so as to place the structure of the network as x.^3 in the first layer of the neural network later?

Comment: this is just the function for generating the training data, so it can be anything.